# How can I get /dev/i2c-* devices to appear on Alpine Linux?

Tags: i2c, pi-zero-w

I have loaded the appropriate kernel modules and set them to load upon boot (`i2c-dev` and `i2c_bcm2835`). A call to `lsmod` confirms that they do indeed load on boot. But alas, I don't see any i2c devices appearing in `/dev`. There is no `/boot/config.txt` file in Alpine.

Has anyone else come across this problem before? What might a next step be to figuring out what's wrong? Thanks.

EDIT: I've been reading more... could this have anything to do with device tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to announce the I²C hardware to the i2c_bcm2835 module. It's not hardcoded, but controlled by the DTB loaded at boot. Add

```
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
```

to `/boot/config.txt` or `/boot/usercfg.txt`.

### You may also need to load the module

Source: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_up_lm_sensors

#### Load it once

```sh
modprobe i2c-dev
```

#### Make it permanent

```sh
echo 'i2c-dev' > /etc/modules-load.d/i2c.conf
```

Comment: There is no `/boot/config.txt` file in Alpine.

Comment: Then, either the boot partition /dev/mmcblk0p1 is not mounted by default, or you are running with the default configuration and simply had to create that file. But first check if it is mounted. Creating that file on the root partition will do nothing.

Comment: You're right, `/dev/mmcblk0p1` is not mounted by default. Alpine is not persistent between boots--the entire system is loaded into RAM on boot. Should I just mount it anyway and make the file?

Comment: You have to edit that file on that partition. It's only needed for the built-in bootloader of the Raspberry Pi, you don't need to have it mounted when the system is up.

Comment: Alright, so I noticed that I was probably looking the wrong place for this config file. I was looking for `/media/mmcblk0p1/boot/config.txt` but there actually is a `config.txt` alongside a `start.elf` and `cmdline.txt` in `/media/mmcblk0p1/` so I imagine that's the one. Upon adding the suggested line to the top of `config.txt` in that directory, I indeed got `/dev/i2c-1`!!! Thank you!

Comment: > There is no /boot/config.txt file in Alpine.

There is on a RaspberryPi setup but you need to edit /boot/usercfg.txt instead.